# Does the x gets allocated and initialised 4 times ? If so why is the address not changing?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
        int i = 1;
        int j;
        for(j = 2*i; j < 6; j++){
                //static int x = 5;
                int x = 5;
                x += 2;
                //x = j + i;
                printf("\n i: %d  x: %d ox%x \n",i,x,&x);
          }
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 i: 1    x: 7   ox601020 
 i: 1    x: 7   ox601020 
 i: 1    x: 7   ox601020 
 i: 1    x: 7   ox601020
```

Does the x gets allocated and initialized 4 times? If so why is the address not changing?

Comment: Are you certain the code matches the output?  I would expect `x` to alway  print as `7`.

Comment: That is what I would expect. The integer value of `x` should be `7` on each pass through the loop. (but note the `//static in x = 5;` commented above.) It looks like the output belongs with a `static` designation with `x = 2;` followed by `x += 1;`.

Comment: If you remove a plate from a stack and replace it several times, does the location of the plate change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything between the braces `{` and `}` of the `for` loop is a separate `block` of code or `code block`. Initializing `x` within the `for` loop is fine because `x` is only within `scope` during each iteration of the for loop. Since `x` is allocated from the stack, it is simply assigned a fixed offset on the stack (thanks to Jim Balter for clarification) which is seen as providing the same address each time.

Additionally, `%p` is preferred for printing pointer values. Hope this helps.

Comment: In most (that is, all that you will encounter) implementations, there is no allocation/deallocation of x during the loop ... it is assigned a fixed offset on the stack and it stays there. Of course the C standard doesn't allow you to count on that.

Comment: Such attributions aren't necessary. SO aims to be a timeless repository of questions and answers ... future readers will benefit from the information, with no interest in who provided it. (And they can always see that here in the comments.)

Answer (score 3):

`x` lives on the stack. For a given call stack frame, it will always have the same address.

Note that it will be initialized four times. Each time through the loop it is effectively "deallocated", "reallocated" and "reinitialized"; however, compilers will typically optimize this stack usage and skip the deallocation and reallocation.

Comment: note that even if x is allocated on heap, nothing prevents the OS from allocating it to the same address since it was deallocated before

Comment: "it will always have the same address" -- This is not guaranteed by the C standard, which has no reference to a stack. "compilers will typically optimize this stack usage" -- x will stay in place even in the absence of optimization. Actual compilers allocate a stack slot for each local variable (and temporary); allocation/deallocation is a conceptual operation in the standard but doesn't actually occur. The only optimization is that compilers will use the same slot for locals with non-overlapping lifetimes.